# Visual studio code Unverified breakpoint for PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, javascript-debugger

My issues is, that VSC does not brake on a brake-point while debugging PhantomJS file.. 
There is only 1 js file. !  I did re-installed VSC, phantomjs, etc.. But no luck.?!

I did followed [tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/iradul/vscode-phantomjs-debug), also googled about this issue, but still VSC just displays:

> Unverified breakpoint, Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "phantomjs",
        "request": "launch",
        "file": "C:/Users/TSS/Desktop/PhantomJS/bin/hello.js",
        "webRoot": "C:/Users/TSS/Desktop/PhantomJS",
        "runtimeExecutable": "C:/Users/TSS/Desktop/PhantomJS/bin/phantomjs.exe",
        "runtimeArgs": [],
        "scriptArgs": [],
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
]
```

}

Folders structure is also very simpple:[image: Folders structure]

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded to older VSC version and it works.. For some reason !